# How to connect XPC Service that is already running with Application, cocoa mac os x app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I have created a XPC Service and communicate with App, if XPC service run by App.

1. When I quit the app, then the XPC service also quits. I want to keep the XPC service alive
2. If XPC service is already running (launch by launchAgent), and now I run the application, then one more new instance is created for XPC service, but I want to connect with the already running XPC sService that is launch by launchAgent, I don't want create new instance at every launch of application.

Please provide the solution to make NSXPCConnection with already running service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks marc_s, Do you have a solution of above problem.